# Get screen DPI in react native

Tags: react-native, dpi

**Context:**

I am trying to create an app that is able to use real world dimensions. In my particular case, it is OK if it's not 100% accurate; however, the more accurate the better.

For example: If I am trying to display a 3cm wide square and in actuality I display a 2.8cm wide square, that is acceptable.

**Problem:**

While there appears to be ways to get a screen's width & height in pixels, there is no way to get either the screen DPI or the screen's width & height in cm/in.

**My Question:** How can I get or calculate the screen's DPI? If this isn't possible, is there another way to try and use a real world measurement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try using React Native's [PixelRatio.get()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio#get) to calculate this.  This method will return a multiplier with `1` equalling an mdpi screen (`160 dpi`).  So if `PixelRatio.get()` returns `1.5`, then its an hdpi screen (`160 * 1.5 = 240 dpi`).

On an mdpi screen:

```
1 inch = 160 pixels
1 inch = 2.54 cm
-----------------------
1 cm = 62.992126 pixels
```

So to render something 3cm wide on this screen, it will need to be 189 pixels.

Likewise, on an xhdpi screen (`PixelRatio.get() = 2`) for example:

```
1 inch = 320 pixels
1 inch = 2.54 cm
-----------------------
1 cm = 125.98425 pixels
```

Something 3cm wide will have to be 378 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly true, you are calculating an **approximation** of the dpi but not the actual dpi.

pixelRatio intervienes between real pixel and independent pixel:

```
    real pixel distance (px) = pixelRatio * independente pixel distance (dp)
```

exemple with Huawei Y9s (2019)  *metrics from https://yesviz.com/devices.php*

```
  width in independant pixel = 360 dp
  width in real pixel = 1080 px
  density in independant pixel = 130 dip
  density in real pixel = 391 dpi
  ratio = 3
  
  the upper formula gives us: 360dp * 3 ≈ 1080px => all good    

  but ratio = 3 
  is different from : dpi / 160 = 391 /160 = 2.44
```

Android makes a confusion between the actual independant density and the bucket density value. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhszwkcay2A)

---

But the rendering is different, if you show a div of 320dp on two apple devices :

```
Ipad Pro 12.9'' (2020) with 132 density in independant pixels => div is printed 61mm or 2.36inch on the screen

Iphone 11 (2019) with 163 density in independant pixels => div is printed 50mm or 2inch on the screen
```

---

So technically, density independant pixel can be approximated to 160dip on every devices

And the corresponding **approximation** of density in real pixel : The bucket density value. Let's call it ~dpi. Can be retrieve with the pixelRatio

```
~dpi = pixelRatio * 160
```